# How can I have two identities with the same e-mail and password?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Some time ago, I asked
[What is the location of lock screen images on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1126403/what-is-the-location-of-lock-screen-images-on-windows-10)

A link on another site sent me there, but I was asked to log in.  Used the same ID and password as always, but it created a new account.  My picture and name are on the question, but I can't accept the answer.

Comment: At least as of right now, the account that you're asking with here is the same account that has asked the question on Super User. If you go to http://superuser.com/users/current what page/user ID are you being sent to?

Comment: Someone must have moved the question to this account.  When I go there, the cookies automatically sign me in as user4911647 who now has NO questions.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing to do in this instance is to [contact us](/contact). In order to work this out, we're going to need to discuss which email addresses you've used in the past, and then make sure any appropriate merges take place. Best to do this via email (and please use a reliable / safe email address when contacting us). You can point to this meta post while contacting us for some background. We'll get it sorted out quickly.